# If $A+B+C+D=2\pi$, prove that:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $A+B+C+D=2\pi$, prove that: $$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C+\cos D=4\cos\frac {A+B}{2}\cdot\cos\frac {A+C}{2}\cdot\cos\frac {B+C}{2}$$.

My Approach:

Here,
$$A+B+C+D=2\pi$$
$$A+B=2\pi - (C+D)$$
$$ \sin(A+B)=\sin(2\pi-(C+D))$$
$$\sin(A+B)=-\sin(C+D)$$

Again,

$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(2\pi-(C+D))$$
$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(C+D)$$

Now,

$$L.H.S=\cos A+\cos B+\cos C+\cos D$$
$$=2 \cos\frac {A+B}{2}\cdot\cos\frac {A-B}{2} + 2 \cos\frac {C+D}{2}\cdot \cos\frac {C-D}{2}$$.

I got stuck at here. Please help me to complete the proof.

Comment: I think you're missing $D$ from the right hand side of your initial equation.

Comment: Could you please pin point the step?

Comment: The line after 'prove that:' - $D$ is on the left hand side, but does not appear on the right hand side.

Comment: C+D = 2π-A-B
C-D = A+B+2C-2π = A+C + B+C - 2π

Comment: But in the question given in my book, $D$ does not appear in $R.H.S$.

Comment: You don't miss anything, I think equation is OK, just try to kill D from your last line, try it way I wrote earlier

Comment: Yup - looks like that works, I was surprised to see no $D$ on the $R.H.S$! Hope @DjuraMarinkov's comment has helped you to solve it!

Comment: I could not get to the point still.

Comment: So,by symmetry  dropping any angle, $$ \cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cdot\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\cdot\cos \frac{C+A}{2}=$$
$$\cos\frac {B+C}{2}\cdot\cos\frac {C+D}{2}\cdot\cos \frac {D+B}{2}= $$
$$ \cos\frac {C+D}{2}\cdot\cos\frac {D+A}{2}\cdot\cos\frac {A+D}{2} ??$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use $2\cos X \cos Y = \cos(X+Y) + \cos(X-Y)$.

\begin{align*}
4\cos \frac{A+B}{2}\cos \frac{A+C}{2} \cos\frac{B+C}{2} &= 2\left(\cos\left(A + \frac{B+C}{2}\right) + \cos\frac{B-C}{2}\right)\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\\
&= 2\cos\left(A + \frac{B+C}{2}\right)\cos\frac{B+C}{2} + 2 \cos\frac{B-C}{2}\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\\
&= \cos(A+B+C) + \cos A + \cos B + \cos C \\
&= \cos(2\pi - D) + \cos A + \cos B + \cos C \\
&= \cos A + \cos B + \cos C + \cos D
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$cos\frac{C+D}{2}=cos\frac{2\pi-(A+B)}{2}=-cos\frac{A+B}{2}$$
$$cos\frac{C-D}{2}=cos\frac{C+A+B+C-2\pi}{2}=-cos\frac{A+C+B+C}{2}$$
Now go to your last line
$$2cos\frac{A+B}{2}(cos\frac{A-B}{2}+cos\frac{A+C+B+C}{2})$$
Use the rule to turn an addition of cosinuses to a multiplication and you will get your proof

Answer (score 2):

As $D=2\pi-(A+B+C),\cos D=\cos(A+B+C)$

$$\implies\cos A+\cos B+\cos C+\cos(A+B+C)$$

$$=2\cos\dfrac{A+B}2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+2\cos\dfrac{A+B+C-C}2\cos\dfrac{A+B+C+C}2$$  (using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html))

$$=2\cos\dfrac{A+B}2\left(\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+\cos\dfrac{A+B+2cc}2\right)$$

Apply Prosthaphaeresis Formula on $$\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+\cos\dfrac{A+B+2C}2$$